# WebStorm Angular support

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I have WebStorm 2016.1.3 and it has Angular plugin installed, but when I open some html file with angular directives i get "Attribute ng-something is not allowed here" all over them.

What exactly I'm I suppose to do to make it go away ?

Answer (score 1):

To enable AngularJS support for your project, you need to have `angular.js` file (debug version, non-compressed, not obfuscated!) in your project (either in your project directory or configured as JavaScript library).  See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/, '`Include angular.js in Your Project`' section. See also http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Try going to:

settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries

And check off angular

[image]

Comment: i don't have it there, it's only in plugins: Version: 145.1616.9

Comment: can you add it by clicking the `Add...` button? Or if you go to the script tag where you are including Angular and hit Alt + Enter is there an option to download it?

Comment: i went away after I alt+enter download it ... so do i need to download it every time for every new file?